# iOS: Changing the story board doesn't reflect on the simulator using a Tab View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabs, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

iOS newbie here.

I created a new "Tabbed Application" Project on Xcode. The storyboard had a tab view controller and two tabs by default called **Item 1** and **Item 2**.

I deleted the two default tabs, created three new view controllers and connected them to the tab view controller, which gave the tab bar view controller three tabs.

When I launch the app on the iOS simulator, it still shows two tabs called Item 1 and Item 2, even though I added new tabs and changed their names.

This is the storyboard:

[image: Storyboard]

This is the simulator:

[image: Simulator]

Comment: try to reset your simulator and run

Comment: @JayGajjar I tried, CMD+Q and re-ran it. Didn't work.

Comment: @FaresK.A. iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings

Comment: @raurora Tried that too, nothing. :/

Answer (score 0):

So, I fixed it by deleting the app from the simulator and building it again. Must have been a bug with the simulator. :/ Thanks everyone!

Comment: Nice, good to know! By the way, when you do 'Reset Content and Settings' - you delete the app from the simulator as well. Also, make it a good habit to do `Shift-Command-K` - Cleaning Xcode just works before building/running.

Comment: @raurora Thank you! I did do that, and I noticed it deleted all of the apps. But for some reason that still didn't work. Thanks again!